# Using $_GET to fetch data from MySql via that id. If the ?id=2dsfajhf it fetches data from id "2" in the db

Tags: php, mysql

As the title says, very simple script and I've never run into this problem before. Just fetching the data for a news system. The id I'm testing is "2" in the database. but if I do article.php?id=2fjfkhshs it displays the info for id "2" instead of the error. "id" is an A_I primary int in the database.

```
       <?php
          $nid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
          $newsQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = '$nid' LIMIT 1");
          $newsExist = mysql_num_rows($newsQuery);
          $newsData = mysql_fetch_array($newsQuery);

          if ($newsExist == 1) {
            echo $newsData['title'];
          }
          else {
            echo "error";
          }
          ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL when comparing a number to a string, the string is cast to a number also.

```
SELECT 2 = '2abcdxyz';
```

Results in `1`

Basically when casting a string to a number the string is just truncated to the first non numeric character.

```
SELECT CAST('2zbcxyz' AS UNSIGNED INTEGER);
```

Results in `2`

Instead, for an exact match, you could use:

```
SELECT BINARY 2 = '2abcdxyz';
```

See it in action here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01abf/2